# how do I install ashmem or binder?

Tags: linux, debian, repository

I have recently installed anbox, and I have gotten it to the point that I can see it's icon, but it can't start due to the ashmem and binder not being installed. I have attempted to install them from the repository, but it just says that it can't find one and the other has no installation candidate. any help would be appreciated big time. linux version is debian jessie.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try building and installing the kernel modules yourself.

1. Download anbox from github [1] so that you have the ashmem and binder directories.
2. Extract ashmem and biinder into /usr/
3. Rename the folders to anbox-ashmem-1 and anbox-binder-1 (the 1 is the version number in dkms.conf)

```
install dkms if not already installed(sudo aptitude install dkms)
sudo dkms add -m anbox-binder -v 1
sudo dkms build -m anbox-binder -v 1
sudo dkms install -m anbox-binder -v 1
sudo modprobe ashmem-linux binder-linux
```

[1] https://github.com/anbox/anbox/archive/master.zip

Comment: I just downloaded https://github.com/anbox/anbox/archive/master.zip and there are no "ashmem" and "binder" folders.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky It is in https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules (but for me it was already here and just needed to be loaded with modprobe: https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/211#issuecomment-1686091709).